# how can I programmatically detect own device's nfc tag using Flutter or Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am trying to develop an NFC-based app using Flutter. but according to requirements, I need to detect users' nfc tags without using any nfc reader. is it possible? For Flutter I'm using the `nfc_manager` package. but I'm not sure how to do this, or if is there any option available or not.

my app mainly focuses on Android devices. so if there is any way to do this using native (kotlin/java), I'm okay with that.

Comment: When the NFC service on an Android device is active the device will permamentely send out signals that powers a near by NFC tag. Depending on the tag and it's technologies it will respond to the signal. If you are running an app with enabled reader mode the resonses will be directed to your app and you can work with the data. How do you want to "detect users' nfc tags without using any nfc reader" when not using an activated NFC reader ?

Comment: well, I was thinking about creating a database where I will store some info alongside the user's NFC tag. so the first time it detects the device tag it will create an entry inside the DB. and next time if another device, with NFC reader, read the tag then I can query the data from my db. I'm not sure if it will work or not. and it will call an HTTP request which is also a downside for my app. I was thinking about Beam NDEF. but still struggling to figure it out, cause I'm very new to Android dev.